# BDD SeleniumGRID ChromeDriver initiated Exception in Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am doing selenium GRID Automation in BDD/Cucumber with Python 3.8 which gives an error while running with Jenkins pipeline with Docker Hub container.

Answer for this Error:

> SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: DH_KEY_TOO_SMALL] dh key too small (_ssl.c:1123)')))

Reason for this error:

> Python 3.8 having validation check of SSL Cipher text with Linux Operation system in Jenkins Docker Hub Pipeline execution.

To avoid this issue: [Solution]

> To resolve this issue, we need to paste below command on top of runnerfile or any PageFactory file with SSL flag OFF to validate.

```
import requests

requests.packages.urllib3.util.ssl_.DEFAULT_CIPHERS = 'ALL:@SECLEVEL=1'
```

Answer (score 0):

Reason for this error:

> Python 3.8 having validation check of SSL Cipher text with Linux Operation system in Jenkins Docker Hub Pipeline execution.

To Avoid this issue: [Solution]

> To resolve this issue, we need to paste below command on top of runnerfile or any PageFactory file with SSL flag OFF to validate.

```
import requests
requests.packages.urllib3.util.ssl_.DEFAULT_CIPHERS = 'ALL:@SECLEVEL=1'
```